# Is it possible to have a short-lived Rust ref that returns None if the object has been deconstructed?

Tags: rust

Could I have something such as

```
struct LongLivedStruct { // lasts for a long time
    possibleRef: ShortLivedRc<SomeTrait> // SomeTrait will be freed soon
}
```

such that I can try to dereference it later:

```
impl LongLivedStruct  {
    fn try_to_do_something(&self) -> &str {
        match &self.possibleRef.try_deref() {
            Ok(_) => "Value still exists, we can do something with it!"
            Err(_) => "Value has already been deconstructed"
        }
    }
}
```

without it panicking if it no longer exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you can do that with a [Weak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) reference.

You can create a weak reference to store in your `LongLivedStruct` by calling [Rc::downgrade](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downgrade) on an `Rc` with your `SomeTrait` object and store it in your `LongLivedStruct`.

Then you can get it back by calling [Weak::upgrade](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.upgrade) on it to get an `Option<Rc<SomeTrait>>` back.